# What are these pans used for?

Tags: baking, equipment, pan

I have these 2 pans and do not know what to cook in them. The square one is non stick; the lid has holes in it and is curved to fit the hump in the bottom part.

The second pan has a detachable handle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Popcorn? (It's a little hard to see the inside of the bottom piece, so I can't tell if there's enough room for that.)

Comment: No it's very shallow with a hump in it

Comment: This is boggling my mind! Is the bottom of the pan flat, creating a hollow space inside the hump? So far my only guess to what it could be used for is flatbread (the way flatbread is made on domed griddles in the Middle East/East) or even possibly flat steak (notice the edge could catch juices) but that's a major stretch I think.

Comment: Where did you get these pans?

Answer (score 4):

Surely it is some sort of gimmicky bacon pan. You lay the bacon over the hump and clamp it down like you would with a bacon press, then the trough-like sides catch the grease.

I could see it maybe being used to make naan bread. Once it's puffed up you clamp the top down and flip upside down to blacken the bubbles like would happen in a tandoor. Seems like a little bit of a stretch though.

Answer (score 1):

Two hypotheses for you:

1. The holes in the lid resemble a colander and make me think there's some steamer functionality for the pan.
2. This might be a stretch, but perhaps it could be used to make spatzle, see here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spätzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A4tzle). I can't tell how deep the pan is from the picture but perhaps you cook the dough in the pan and turn the pan over to let the water out through the holes of the lid.

I'm curious to hear what other people think!